# Flex Project Views with the same name

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, view, project

I have a Flex project which links to additional projects.  Some of these additional projects have mxml views with the same name (i.e. the main project is referencing two other projects which both have a 'Main.mxml').  I want to be able to add both of these 'Main.mxml' views as children in my project, but when I create a new view, I can only see one 'Main.mxml'.  Is there a way in Actionscript for me to access these views and add them even though they have the same name (using Flex 4.6)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your two Main.mxml files have the same package name, then you will not be able to use them both in the same project.

If they have different package names; you can use them both but may have to fully qualify the package names whenever creating a class.

How are your projects linked? Are the 'linked' projects library projects?

Comment: I have them added as 'Additional Source Folders' in the 'Flex Build Path' properties.  They are essentially fully functioning projects on their own, but I want to link to certain views in them from this 'parent' project.